# Running program which takes inputs from config file using command prompt

Tags: python, configparser

Running python program which takes inputs from config file using command prompt.

`abc.cfg` - config file:

```
[values]
x = 10
```

`abc.py` - python script:

```
import configparser

configs = configparser.ConfigParser()
configs.read('abc.cfg')
x1 = int(configs['values']['x'])

def main():
   y1 = x1 + 1
   print(y1)

main()
```

While running the code in command prompt I am facing some issues as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\john123\PycharmProjects\ParsingLogFiles\abc.py", line 5, in <module>
    x1 = int(configs['values']['x'])
  File "C:\Users\john123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'values'
```

`C:\Users\john123\PycharmProjects\ParsingLogFiles` is the location of my `abc.py` and `abc.cfg` files.

Comment: Code works fine for me. Do you think File location is proper?

Comment: Why don't you use a txt file, or even a different python script if you just wan to use one variable

Comment: @Kris C:\Users\john123\PycharmProjects\ParsingLogFiles\Parsing.py is the location of file

Comment: The only time this will usually happen is if the key is not in the read file. Are you positive `[values]` is in `abc.cfg`? something tells me it's not.

Comment: @ I'L'i [values] is in the abc.cfg